# Singular or plural verb in function name?

Tags: coding-style, naming-conventions

Take Java standard library as an example, why is not `Object.equals` called Object.equal? And why is `Object.clone` used singular from, not Object.clones?

Why do I see almost all people use `getXXX` and `setXXX` in reading and setting properties of an object, not gets or sets?

Comment: Because all the "why not"'s you have are not the correct word forms? But this isn't really the place to be giving English lessons, nor am I the person that should be giving them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Those method names are verbs, not nouns. `equals` is the third-person form of the verb "equal"  (likely interrogative -- in languages that support non-alphanumeric characters in method names it's often called `equals?`), and `clone` is the second-person imperative form of the verb "clone" (you're ordering the object: "clone yourself!").

In general, you use interrogative verbs for methods that query information about the object state relative to another (`equals`, `contains`, `hasXXX`...), imperative verbs for "action" methods (methods that ask the object to perform some task, e.g. `clone`, `add`, `show`... Very often these methods don't return anything), and nouns for methods that query information about the object's state without referencing anything external (e.g. `length`, `intValue`, `keys`). Note that those nouns can be singular or plural depending on what the method returns: singular for something that can only be singular (`length`), plural for something that can return a list/map/other container (`keys`).

Getters are a special case, where you use an action verb (get) to "tag" these methods as getters, and for symmetry with setters that use set.

Also, getters/setters are a workaround for the lack of properties in C++ and Java. In a language without that weakness, they don't exist: you use properties instead, and *those* are nouns.